# Ошибка авторизации VK Auth

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, авторизация

При попытке авторизации через контакт:

> https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=xxxxxx&display=popup&redirect_uri=https://site.com/verify&scope=friends&response_type=token&v=5.68

Вылазит ошибка:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Security Error"}
```

Она отображается по адресу:

> https://oauth.vk.com/error?err=2

Ошибка возникает только в случае, если захожу под пользователем со старой сессией Вконтакте. При авторизации через пользователя со свежей сессией или когда перелогинятся все работает нормально. На других сайтах то же самое. Никакого перенаправления на Redirect URI хотя бы с кодом ошибки тоже не происходит (в документации написано, что перенаправление идет).

Сейчас разработчики VK предлагают следующее решение:

> Ошибка часто появляется, если у вас старая сессия. Нужно просто
>   перелогиниться в браузерной версии.

Как понимаете, это не совсем нормальное решение. Обычные пользователи не будут логиниться заново, только чтобы пройти регистрацию (они даже не будут знать об этом, т.к. просто вылазит окно с ошибкой).

Кто сталкивался с этой проблемой? Как ее можно решить, чтобы авторизация проходила для всех пользователей, в том числе со старыми сессиями?